# Possible to create custom urls with RESTful routing in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, routes, custom-url

Is it possible to have custom urls without renaming controller methods when using RESTful routing with `Route::controller`?

With `Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');` I want the url to be `users/registration` instead of `users/create` without renaming `getCreate` method in `UsersController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Before `Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');` in your routes, you can add the following line:

```
Route::get('users/registration', 'UsersController@getCreate');
```

By doing that you're explicitly specifying that you want the `GET` request for `users/registration` to be handled by `getCreate` method on the `UsersController` class.